# Toggle Dark/Light Mode in Windows 10 automatically by time of day (without modifying or changing theme!)

Tags: powershell, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, darkmode

Nowadays most devices allow for an automatic toggle of Dark/Light mode, however Windows 10 doesn't seem to have such a feature. Is there a way to accomplish this? Using the Task Scheduler for example?

There seem to be many examples on how to change the windows "theme" programmatically, but not the light/dark mode toggle (which can be independently set for "windows mode" or for "app mode" in Settings/Colors).

[image: Windows 10 settings Colors dark/light mode section]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is!

It can be a bit tricky to pull off seamesly, but it can be done with the following steps:

Open Task Scheduler and create a new task with the following settings:

*General*

[image: General task settings]

- "Run whether user is logged in or not" is required so that a powershell window doesn't flash every time this runs.
- "Do not Store Password" check since it's an offline script
- "Run with highest priviledges" just to be sure nothing interrupts it (optional)

*Triggers*

[image: trigger task settings on logon]
[image: trigger task settings every hour since midnight]

- Add one trigger for "On workstation unlock"
- Add one trigger to repeat every hour

*Actions*

[image: action for running PS script]

- Add an Action with Program=Powershell and Arguments=`$time=(Get-Date).TimeOfDay.Hours; if($time -gt 8 -and $time -lt 19){"Setting Light theme..";Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force; Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force} else {"Setting Dark theme..."; Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force; Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force;}`

That PS script seems like a lot packed into a single line, but that's just so we can paste it in that "arguments" diaglog in the Action. So let's break it down a bit to see what it does:

```
# Set current time in a variable
$time=(Get-Date).TimeOfDay.Hours; 
# if later than 8am and earlier than 7pm, use light mode
if($time -gt 8 -and $time -lt 19){ 
    "Setting Light theme.."; # output in case we let a window be opened
    # set "app" system mode to "light"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force; 
    # set "OS" system mode to "light"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force; 
} else {
    "Setting Dark theme..."; # output in case we let a window be opened
    # set "app" system mode to "dark"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force; 
    # set "OS" system mode to "dark"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 0 -Type Dword -Force; 
}
```

*Update:*

Although neatly-compact, maintaining code in a single line can be a hassle, so if you prefer to keep your PS script in a `.ps1` file, you can excecute it from there simply by putting `Powershell.exe` (or `pwsh.exe`) in the Program box, and then `-file C:\yourscript.ps1` as argument):

[image: Task Scheduler action excecuting file instead of on-line command]

Comment: Thanks. I made this thingy to switch back and forth: https://gist.github.com/vctls/027f02644c582be9a4f6214150ea3d70

Comment: This solution works well in Windows 10, but not in Windows 11. See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1754010/how-to-enable-light-mode-dark-mode-in-windows-11-programatically

Comment: Task scheduler seems to mess it up when hibernating for some reason, so there's still room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the Task Scheduler for all timing and `Reg` to toggle the registry keys.

1. Create a task.

   - General > Name > "Turn on Light Mode".
   - Triggers > New... > Daily > **set your desired Light Mode start time**.
   - Actions > New...

     - Action > Start a program
     - Program/script > `Reg`
     - Add arguments
       `add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize /v AppsUseLightTheme /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`
2. Create a task.

   - General > Name > "Turn on Dark Mode".
   - Triggers > New... > Daily > **set your desired Dark Mode start time**.
   - Actions > New...

     - Action > Start a program
     - Program/script > `Reg`
     - Add arguments
       `add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize /v AppsUseLightTheme /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

For each task enable these Settings.
[image]

Comment: Simple nice easy ! For me best answer ! +1

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment on GollyJer's post due to a lack of rep. The only issue with it I found is that it doesn't change the Windows colour theme (taskbar etc).

Here is the second line to change the "Windows Mode" colour theme:

`reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize /v SystemUsesLightTheme /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

I ended up putting both lines in two separate bat files and just pointed the task to the script. Could probably just use one script for both and pass it a command from the task as an argument if one was so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

**Slim solution with AutoHotKey (AHK)**

User erbanku proposed a solution with AutoHotKey (AHK) in his post "Switch between Light & Dark Mode on Windows 11 using AHK":
https://gist.github.com/erbanku/eac274bc41baf6fd100013020a8de151

Copy of his code:

```
;Switch between Light & Dark Mode on Windows 11

;IN THIS CASE, APPS ON WINDOWS 11 WILL USE LIGHT/DARK MODE
^#!A::
; read current theme
RegRead, CurrentTheme, % "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize", % "AppsUseLightTheme"

; toggle between themes
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, % "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize", % "AppsUseLightTheme", % 1 - CurrentTheme
Return

;IN THIS CASE, SYSTEMS ON WINDOWS 11 WILL USE LIGHT/DARK MODE
^#!L::
; read current theme
RegRead, CurrentTheme, % "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize", % "SystemUsesLightTheme"

; toggle between themes
RegWrite, REG_DWORD, % "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize", % "SystemUsesLightTheme", % 1 - CurrentTheme
Return
```