# Toogle Light/Dark Mode Programmatically in Windows 11

Tags: windows, registry

I would like to toggle light / dark mode on Windows 11 programmatically.

Existing solutions are unsatisfactory:

1. [use the Registry values "AppsUseLightTheme" and "SystemUsesLightTheme"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73734301/toggle-dark-light-mode-in-windows-10-automatically-by-time-of-day-without-modif). This worked perfectly in Windows 10. However, in Windows 11 the change is not applied in all places. For example, when switching to dark mode, Explorer windows are still light. And the clock text in the right corner of the Taskbar is still black, so now the clock cannot be read anymore.
2. [select a different Theme programmatically](https://superuser.com/a/1754092/121093) - however, this changes my Desktop background. I'd really just like to change the dark/light mode and keep everything else the same.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Microsoft has been really bad at exposing these things to 3rd-party applications the last few years, doubt there is anything official. Maybe an undocumented function in uxtheme?