# Toggle Dark/Light Mode in Windows 11 automatically by time of day (without modifying or changing theme!)

Tags: windows, powershell, themes, scheduled-tasks

This question follows this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73734301/toggle-dark-light-mode-in-windows-10-automatically-by-time-of-day-without-modif)

And this answers by Sebastián Vansteenkiste: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73734302/14548380)

From his solution, I had to change the argument of my action.

From this: `-file C:\yourscript.ps1`

To this: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\yourscript.ps1`

Otherwise, I had this error:

```
Unable to load file E:\Other\AutomaticallyChangeWindowsTheme.ps1 because script execution is
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
+ CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

But now, when my theme is switched by the task or if I execute the script myself, in the settings my application mode correctly switches:

[image: Screenshot of choose your mod seeting of windows 11]

(From Light (Clair) in Dark (Sombre))

But my file explorer is bugged and don't change:
[image: Screenshot of the file explorer that haven't change completly of theme]

Even if I close and open the file explorer it's still bugged:
[image: Screenshot of the file explorer that haven't change completly of theme]

Is there a command to add to the script to achieve the exact same effect as switching the application mode from my settings?

Thank you in advance for the help!